# Getting plots based on equations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get plots based on an equation using `ggplot2`. Here is what I have done so far:

```
eq <- function(x,a) { 
    g<- (x^2+a+1)
    return(g)
} 
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-10000, 10000)), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = eq, args = list(a=2), aes(colour = "Time"))
```

This gives me the plot. I want to keep the range in the x-axis, i.e., `c(-10000,10000)`, I would like to change the `a`  but keep the `x` in the following code to get the plot, e.g `eq(x,3)`.

So only by changing `a`, I want to get the plot. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you wrap it in a function `fplot <- function(a_val) {
       ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-10000, 10000)), aes(x)) + 
         stat_function(fun = eq, args = list(a=a_val), aes(colour = "Time"))
   
    };
    
 fplot(3)`

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to get two or more curves within a single plot?

Comment: You meant if you pass more than one value for 'a', it would add more stat_function?

Comment: No, within one stat_function?

Comment: I think your range is too big to make this noticeable for smaller 'a'.  You can check `p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-10, 10)), aes(x));for (i in 1:10) {
  p <- p + stat_function(fun =eq,  args=list(a=i)) 
 };p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a smaller range, the lines can be noticeable, when we add `stat_function` based layers to the plot in a `for` loop

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-10, 10)), aes(x))
for (i in 1:10) {  
        p <- p + stat_function(fun = eq,  args=list(a=i))   
   }
p
```

-output

[image]

---

if we want to add some colors

```
v1 <- c(3, 4)
v2 <- seq(15, 400, length = 10 + 1)
v3 <- hcl(h = v2, l = 65, c = 100)[seq_along(v1)]
  
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-10, 10)), aes(x))
for (i in seq_along(v1)) {  
          p <- p + stat_function(fun = eq,  color = v3[i], args=list(a=v1[i]))   
     }
p
```

---

With a larger 'x', the `eq` gives slight changes in the value

```
sapply(1:10, eq, x = c(-10000, 10000))
#    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
#[1,] 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08
#[2,] 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08 1e+08
```

The difference is very negligible compared to the axis range

```
apply(sapply(1:10, eq, x = c(-10000, 10000)), 1, diff)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    1    1
# [5,]    1    1
# [6,]    1    1
# [7,]    1    1
# [8,]    1    1
# [9,]    1    1
```

making it difficult to visually separate the lines

Comment: Thanks again, if I want to have only 2 different curves a, let's say 3 and 4, I don't know what to do ?

Comment: @user330 you can change the `for (i in c(3, 4)) {  
        p <- p + stat_function(fun = eq,  args=list(a=i))   
   }`

Comment: Thank you, I try to sperate two curves by colour, scale_colour_manual(), it does not change?

Comment: @user330 I meant the code block after the `if we want to add some colors` in the solution post